# How to avoid this memory leak?

Tags: c++, methods, memory-leaks, free

This is my code:

```
void MIDITest::CreateNoteBlock() {
    IMidiMsgExt* midiMessage = new IMidiMsgExt;
    midiMessage->MakemidiMessageMsg(57, 100, 0, 0, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(*midiMessage);

    midiMessage = new IMidiMsgExt;
    midiMessage->MakemidiMessageMsg(60, 100, 0, tickSize * 38, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(*midiMessage);

    midiMessage = new IMidiMsgExt;
    midiMessage->MakemidiMessageMsg(62, 100, 0, 0, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(*midiMessage);

    midiMessage = new IMidiMsgExt;
    midiMessage->MakemidiMessageMsg(65, 100, 0, tickSize * 32, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(*midiMessage);

    midiMessage = new IMidiMsgExt;
    midiMessage->MakemidiMessageMsg(57, 0, tickSize * 111, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(*midiMessage);

    midiMessage = new IMidiMsgExt;
    midiMessage->MakemidiMessageMsg(60, 0, tickSize * 111, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(*midiMessage);

    midiMessage = new IMidiMsgExt;
    midiMessage->MakemidiMessageMsg(62, 0, tickSize * 75, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(*midiMessage);

    midiMessage = new IMidiMsgExt;
    midiMessage->MakemidiMessageMsg(65, 0, tickSize * 105, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(*midiMessage);
}
```

so at every `new` operator it will allocate a block of memory.

Should I use `free` after any `insert` inside the queuedNotes? Or it will be released after `void` function return? (i.e. the brackets of CreateNoteBlock).

Or I can "reuse" each time the `midiMessage` pointer for a new `IMidiMsgExt`?

Comment: Show us complete code. What is `queuedNotes` ?

Comment: @Chiel this is `multiset<IMidiMsgExt, IMidiMsgExtComp> queuedNotes;`. That's the code: it is called within the CTOR of a class.

Comment: What about using 'IMidiMsgExt midiMessage;' instead of 'IMidiMsgExt* midiMessage = new IMidiMsgExt'?

Comment: Doesn't matter, really, *midiMessage is passing by value, that is, a copy is made. queuedNotes cannot take ownership of the pointer. So yes, you'll have to delete for every new.

Comment: You should **never** use `free` on something that was created with `new`. `free` is used together with `malloc`; for `new` you have to use `delete`. Don't mix them, ever! Mixing them is like renting a car from Avis and giving it back to Hertz, it's simply wrong! And in C++ you shouldn't use `malloc` and `free`, only `new` and `delete` (leaving aside smart pointers), because you don't just want to allocate/reclaim memory, you also want the constructors/destructors to run. Please check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free

Comment: @AdrianRoman. Only true when a proper deepcopy is implemented for `IMidiMsgExt`. Otherwise it is a choice between undefined behavior or a memory leak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is not to use `new` at all.  Create a object with automatic storage duration

```
IMidiMsgExt midiMessage;
```

And then you can keep calling `MakemidiMessageMsg` and insert a copy of the message into the `multiset`.

```
midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(57, 100, 0, 0, 0);
queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);
midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(60, 100, 0, tickSize * 38, 0);
queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);
//...
```

Now the `multiset` has a copy of all of the messages and at the end of the function `midiMessage` is destroyed and no memory management needs to be done.

If `IMidiMsgExt` has a constructor that is like `MakemidiMessageMsg` where you can construct a complete message then you could boild this down even further and use something like

```
queuedNotes.insert(IMidiMsgExt(57, 100, 0, 0, 0));
queuedNotes.insert(IMidiMsgExt(60, 100, 0, tickSize * 38, 0));
```

And now we don't even need `midiMessage`.

Comment: But at the end of the function won't "all" midiMessage (created by using new) destroyed as well?

Comment: @paizza No.  If you call `new` the only way to free the memory is to call `delete`.  The pointer is destroyed but the memory will not be automatically returned.

Comment: It's due to automatic storage duration right? So your suggestion is about `automatic storage duration`, `new` about `dynamic storage duration` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337294/creating-an-object-with-or-without-new

Comment: Can I create a `automatic storage duration` using pointer? Or that's valid only using object itself and not pointer?

Comment: @paizza You can but those are called smart pointers and there is really not a need for them from what I see here,  If all you want to do is create messages and and add them to the multiset then pretend that pointers don't exist.  Pointers have there uses but in C++ if can use an object with automatic storage duration you should.  It is almost like 0 cost garbage collection.

Comment: Ok. Not sure why I should use pointer or object so. It's a guess for the moment. For what I see, many methods use pointer instead of passing directly the object. So i need to use `&var` every time instead of create pointer and just pass `var`.

Comment: It could be that what you are seeing is a C interface.  In C the only way to pass an object to a function without making a copy was to pass by pointer.  In C++ we have references which abstracts that away and allows us to pass without copying and gets rid of having to use `&variable_name` when calling the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109821/discussion-between-paizza-and-nathanoliver).

Answer (score 5):

Do you come from a Java or C# background? In C++ you don't have to use `new` to create objects, just declaring them will work fine:

```
IMidiMsgExt midiMessage;
midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(57, 100, 0, 0, 0);
queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);
```

It's either that (which is my recommended solution), or you have to explicitly free the objects:

```
IMidiMsgExt* midiMessage = new IMidiMsgExt;
midiMessage->MakemidiMessageMsg(57, 100, 0, 0, 0);
queuedNotes.insert(*midiMessage);
delete miniMessage;
```

Comment: Yes, I'm a C# programmer.

Answer (score 1):

It seem redundant to dynamically allocate `IMidiMsgExt` using new.  You can just allocate it directly on the stack (no pointers), and then it will be destroyed when your method returns.  I.e.:

```
void MIDITest::CreateNoteBlock() {
    IMidiMsgExt midiMessage();
    midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(57, 100, 0, 0, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    midiMessage = IMidiMsgExt();
    midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(60, 100, 0, tickSize * 38, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    midiMessage = IMidiMsgExt();
    midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(62, 100, 0, 0, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    midiMessage = IMidiMsgExt();
    midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(65, 100, 0, tickSize * 32, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    midiMessage = IMidiMsgExt();
    midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(57, 0, tickSize * 111, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    midiMessage = IMidiMsgExt();
    midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(60, 0, tickSize * 111, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    midiMessage = IMidiMsgExt();
    midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(62, 0, tickSize * 75, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    midiMessage = IMidiMsgExt();
    midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(65, 0, tickSize * 105, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your API more C++ like.

Use one object on the stack instead of creating a lot of new ones in the heap.

```
void MIDITest::CreateNoteBlock() {
    IMidiMsgExt midiMessage;

    midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(57, 100, 0, 0, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    midiMessage.MakemidiMessageMsg(60, 100, 0, tickSize * 38, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    // ...
}
```

Initialize your objects in the constructor. Define an `operator = (const IMidiMsgExt&)` for `IMidiMsgExt`.

```
void MIDITest::CreateNoteBlock() {
    IMidiMsgExt midiMessage(57, 100, 0, 0, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    midiMessage = IMidiMsgExt(60, 100, 0, tickSize * 38, 0);
    queuedNotes.insert(midiMessage);

    // ...
}
```

I guess, that `insert()` expects a `const IMidiMsgExt&`. So you can directly pass freshly initialized objects:

```
void MIDITest::CreateNoteBlock() {
    queuedNotes.insert({57, 100, 0, 0, 0});
    queuedNotes.insert({60, 100, 0, tickSize * 38, 0});

    // ...
}
```

BTW: you should prefer to use e.g. `std::queue<>` for `queuedNotes`. Then you'll not use `insert()`, but `push()`, or `emplace()`. The advantage of `emplace()` is, that it constructs the object in the container instead of first creating it and then copying it to the container:

```
void MIDITest::CreateNoteBlock() {
    queuedNotes.emplace(57, 100, 0, 0, 0);
    queuedNotes.emplace(60, 100, 0, tickSize * 38, 0);

    // ...
}
```

Also your typename `IMidiMsgExt` signals to me, that you are trying to mimic the C# thinking in C++. It is possible, but usually it is not the preferred solution. From your question I don't know enough about your class tree and the underlying requirements to provide a suggestion, but in C++ that usually is a code smell.