# C++ constructor with istringstream doesn`t work

Tags: c++

i have class with two types of constructor:

```
MyClass(istringstream& is)
{
    string line;
    getline(is, line);

    m_name = line;
}

MyClass() : m_name"whatever" {}
```

but whet I call this in main:

```
MyClass myCLASS;

istringstream is.str("Somestring");

myCLASS(is);
```

Compilator says  error: no match for call to ‘(CTrain) (std::istringstream&)’

Could zou please tell me why?

Comment: Please format your code to allow us understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few errors.

First, your initialiser list is missing a pair of brackets; it should be

```
MyClass() : m_name("whatever") {}
```

Second, your declaration of `is` is wrong - you can't call a function on an object in its own declaration.
It should look like this:

```
istringstream is("Somestring");
```

Third, and the source of the error message, you can't explicitly call a constructor - it's invoked automatically when the object is initialised.

In your code, the `myCLASS` object has already been constructed, and the line

```
myCLASS(is);
```

means "call the function call operator of `MyClass` that can take a `istringstream` as a parameter.

Such a function might look like `void operator() (istringstream&)`, but there is no such thing in your code.
It's also definitely not what you mean.

You should change the order of declaration of your objects, like this:

```
istringstream is("Somestring");
MyClass myCLASS(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor can be only invoked at a point of declaration, not later.

```
  MyClass myCLASS(is); // invokes a constructor
  myCLASS(is); // does not invoke a constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the MyClass constructor after the object of that class had been constructed - you cannot do that. At this line:

```
MyClass myCLASS;
```

the default constructor ( MyClass() ) had already been called. At this line:

```
myCLASS(is);
```

you are calling a constructor of the already instantiated object (i.e. calling the constructor the second time).

In order to work, your code should for example look like this:

```
istringstream is("Somestring");
MyClass myCLASS(is);
```

If you do need to sort of call a contructor of an object that has already been instantiated, you may want to read this:

[Can you invoke an instantiated object's class constructor explicity in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313882/can-you-invoke-an-instantiated-objects-class-constructor-explicity-in-c)